# Using 2 or more cellnote colors in heatmap.2 R

Tags: r, gplots

I'm currently working on a heatmap that uses a complex discrete color scale (about 34 different colors). Some of the colors are dark while others are light. I'm labeling cells with the `cellnote` argument of the `heatmap.2()` function. Since some of the background colors of the cells are very dark, when using a black cellnote color the cell labels can't be seen. Likewise, when using a lighter cellnote color the labels in the cells with a light background color can't be seen. Was wondering if it is possible to have different cellnote colors in a single heatmap produced with the ´heatmap.2()´ function. Here is a small example of the situation:

```
library(gplots)
x <- cbind(c(0.5, 1.5), c(1.5, 0.5))
pal <- c("darkblue", "lightblue")
heatmap.2(
    x,
    Rowv = FALSE,
    Colv = FALSE,
    dendrogram = "none",
    key = FALSE,
    trace = "none",
    col = pal,
    breaks = seq(0, 2),
    cellnote = x,
    notecol = "black",
    notecex = 2
)
```

[image: example]

The desired output would be to have white cellnote in the upper-left and down-right cells while keeping a black cellnote in the other cells. I anticipate this will potentially require to modify the function's [source code](https://github.com/talgalili/gplots/blob/master/R/heatmap.2.R). However, I haven't been able to come up with a solution myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... apparently you can pass a matrix to the `notecol` argument lol. I assumed this wasn't possible initially because in the documentation it said 'string' but well my bad for not trying before. However, for some reason I seem to have to reverse the columns of the color character matrix to actually get the desired result? This is kinda weird but it works:

```
notemat <- cbind(c("white", "black"), c("black", "white"))
heatmap.2(
    x,
    Rowv = FALSE,
    Colv = FALSE,
    dendrogram = "none",
    key = FALSE,
    trace = "none",
    col = pal,
    breaks = seq(0, 2),
    cellnote = x,
    notecol = apply(notemat, 2, rev),
    notecex = 2
)
```

[image: result]